# Sum of a function over all tuples that satisfy a condition?

Tags: summation, notation

I would like to write something like

$$\sum_{x=(i,P_{j,k})}f(i,P_{j,k})\forall k \in \{1,...K\}$$

to express the sum of $f(i,P_{j,k})$ for tuples $x=(i,P_{j,k})$ for all $k \in \{1,...K\}$ .

so basically, the index is k. Is this mathematically correct?

Thank you.

Comment: No, this is not correct usage of summation notation.  If the index of summation is $k$, then $k$ should be used as the index.  Also, you write "tuples that satisfy a condition" but you don't say what is the condition!  The way you have written it, it seems like you are summing over all $k$ with $1 \le k \le K$, which is not a condition on the tuple but a condition on $k$.  Also, $x$ is completely out of context: what is $x$ doing there at all?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm trying to sum over k that's true, but at the same time, i want to include only tuples with parameters equal to $ i,P_{j,k}$

Comment: so for $k=1,i=2, j=5$ i want to find $f(2,P_{5,1})$ then similarly for k=2 and so on.

Comment: What does "similarly for $k=2$" mean?  Is it $k=2,i=2,j=5$ or something completely different that you haven't specified?  You still haven't said anything about what the "condition" in the subject line is!

Comment: yes it means for
$k=2, i=2, j=5$ find $f(2,P_{5,2})$
and for 
$k=3, i=2, j=5$ find $f(2,P_{5,3})$
all the way to K and sum those.
the condition here is that this is only done for $i=2,j=5$
meaning that over $1,...K$ only tuples whose $i=2,j=5$ get looked at.

Comment: Again your comments indicate that there is **no** condition that the tuples must satisfy.  Since $k$ is the only thing changing the summation is a completely straightforward $\sum_{k=1}^K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said yourself: the index is $k$, not $x$ (which isn't even used anywhere).  According to your comments above, there is no condition that you are testing the tuples $(i,P_{j,k})$ for, contrary to your subject line.  Therefore, all evidence points to the correct notation being

$$\sum_{k=1}^K f(i,P_{j,k}),$$

which is trivially equivalent to

$$f(i,P_{j,1}) + f(i,P_{j,2}) + \cdots + f(i,P_{j,K}).$$

Comment: thanks, based on your comments, I also eventually arrived at this notation but didn't know it was correct.
Thank you for your help.